# Android App crash because of Null Pointer exception on setting onClick listener in Editor class

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

I have created a Linear Layout onclick of a button which has an edit text. While typing there is a popup window for suggestions that comes up and the app crashes.

Stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
       at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3714)
       at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.(Editor.java:3375)
       at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.(Editor.java:3660)
       at android.widget.Editor.replace(Editor.java:423)
       at android.widget.Editor$3.run(Editor.java:2340)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

I found some related answers which stated that this happens on using Android PopupWindow class since the suggestions are using a PopupWindow as well. My code does not use PopupWindow as well.

This crash is happening mostly on Samsung Note 5, and Galaxy S6.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Cause is view object is null while you are adding click listener.
make null check before setting listener to view object.

Comment: Please go ahead and post your java and xml code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that your button (which you used like `buttonName.setOnClickListener()`) is not defined. Check your find view by id function, id inside of it etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you set in XML a click, but don't have in your class. A check has this tag and remove:

```
android:onClick="save"
```